# How to find $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ functions such that?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, smooth-functions, functional-inequalities

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that exists $p \geq 1$ and an constant $C>0$ that
$$|g(t)| \leq C(|t|+|t|^{p})\,\,\,\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Let be $\eta(t)$ be an function in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and define

$g_1(t)=\eta(t)(t+g(t))$ and $g_2(t)=(1-\eta(t))(t+g(t))$

My question is: It is possible to construct $\eta(t) \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$|g_1(t)| \leq C \min\{1,|t|\}$ and $|g_2(t)| \leq C|t|^{p}$ ?

The possibility of doing the above construction will help me in the process of regularization of an Elliptic PDE, because if the above is true I can divide a harder problem in two easier problems. Thank you very much for the help, any hint will be very helpful.

Comment: For $|t|$ large enough you'll have $g_2=g$...

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I still don't know how to find this function

Comment: It doesn't exist if $g$ is larger than $C|t|^p$ for $|t|$ arbitrary large